# has_child queries fail if queryName is set

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch v0.90.5 and trying to set QueryName (`_name`) for a `has_child` query as described here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html

But the `has_child` queries are failing if queryName is set. They also fail if queryName is set on a wrapping query. You can find the curl recreation here: https://gist.github.com/hmrizin/9645816

```
"query": {
    "has_child": {
        "query": {
            "term": {
               "postid": "p1"
            }
        },
        "child_type": "post",
        "_name": "somename"
    }
}
```

and

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": {
            "has_child": {
                "query": {
                    "term": {
                        "postid": "p2"
                    }
                },
                "child_type": "post"
            }
        },
        "_name": "somename"
    }
}
```

The error that both cause is the same:

```
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 4,
    "failed" : 1,
    "failures" : [ {
      "index" : "twtest",
      "shard" : 1,
      "status" : 500,
      "reason" : "ElasticSearchIllegalStateException[has_child filter hasn't executed properly]"
    } ]
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Just for a sanity check, the queries do work without specifying the `_name`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Having just run this with `v1.0.1`, it worked as-is without any changes.

However, I downloaded `v0.90.5` and it got the error that you posted unless I removed the `_name`. It looks like you came across a bug, and in the very next release, `v0.90.6`, the entire class to blame (`HasChildFilter`) was refactored into other code.

1. `v0.90.5` package: [`org.elasticsearch.index.search.child`](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/tree/v0.90.5/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/search/child)
2. `v0.90.6` package: [`org.elasticsearch.index.search.child`](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/tree/v0.90.6/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/search/child)

It looks like you came across a bug that also existed in `v0.90.4` (I verified), which is when the feature was added. Unfortunately, I think the solution to your problem is to upgrade your installation of Elasticsearch to at least [`v0.90.6`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/downloads/0-90-6/). Based on its patch notes, they may not even have been aware of the error that they fixed, but I was able to verify that it was fixed in that release.